# can't upload file , all element submit but the file element not

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

the file below does not submited , while all form element sumbited , 
find the error in the code below

```
<form enctype = "multipart/form-data" action="tyo.php" method="POST" target="_BLANK"><?php
    echo "
    <input type='hidden' name='File_no' value='$emp_no'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='date' value='$date'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='day' value='$day'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='record_id' value='$record_id' /> 
    <input type='hidden' name='method' value='add_absence' />
    ";                                              
    echo "<td style='text-align:center'>
    <select name='ab_ex'> ";
        $sql_absence = "SELECT * FROM `ex_ab_types`";
        $result_absence = $mysqli->query($sql_absence);
            if ($result_absence->num_rows > 0)
            {   while($row_sql_absence = $result_absence->fetch_assoc()) 
                {
                    echo "<option value='$row_sql_absence[EX_ID]'>$row_sql_absence[DESC]</option>";
                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
    echo"<select>";                                                     
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td >";?>         
    <input type="file" name="attac"  value='' /> 
    <?php echo "</td>";
    echo "<td style='text-align:center'>
        <input type='submit' style='margin-bottom: 0px;' value='save' class='btn btn-primary' />
    </td>"; // submit
echo "</form>";
```

any body help me 
???

Comment: you might want to change your input type `hidden` to a more suitable type

Comment: 5 hidden fields and a select box... Where is your 'submit' element?

Comment: Can you submit the form and post the results.  ie: `var_dump($_POST);` at the top of `tyo.php`

Comment: I get   Undefined index: attac in C:\wamp\www\Attendance\admin\tyo.php on line 3.....                                                                                                   when i use $filename =$_FILES['attac']['name'];

Comment: Suggestions: remove `target='_blank'`, and.. ..rename the 'method' input box.

Comment: MaggesWeb                                                                                                        I get this ......                                                                                                            array (size=6)
  'File_no' => string '484' (length=3)
  'date' => string '2015-10-01' (length=10)
  'day' => string 'Thursday' (length=8)
  'record_id' => string '30653' (length=5)
  'method' => string 'add_absence' (length=11)
  'ab_ex' => string 'AB' (length=2)

Comment: I removed the target but still

Comment: ..rename the 'method' input box.

Comment: I try the rename (method) & the and also remove the blank target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your code is not working.. ..but can you try this form below.  I have taken your form and removed all the PHP.  This should still submit a file to `tyo.php`..

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="tyo.php" method="post">

    <input type='hidden' name='test'   value='123'/>
    <input type="file"   name="attac"  value='' /> 
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='save'  />

</form>
```

**Your code.. ..tidy'd up a bit**

```
<form enctype = "multipart/form-data" action="tyo.php" method="POST">

    <input type='hidden' name='File_no'     value='<?= $emp_no ?>'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='date'        value='<?= $date ?>'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='day'         value='<?= $day ?>'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='record_id'   value='<?= $record_id ?>' /> 
    <input type='hidden' name='method'      value='<?= $add_absence ?>' />
    <td style='text-align:center'>
        <select name='ab_ex'>
        <?php
        $sql_absence = "SELECT * FROM `ex_ab_types`";
        $result_absence = $mysqli->query($sql_absence);
        if ($result_absence->num_rows > 0){
            while($row_sql_absence = $result_absence->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<option value='$row_sql_absence[EX_ID]'>$row_sql_absence[DESC]</option>";
            }
        }
        ?><select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="file" name="attac"  value='' /> 
    </td>
    <td style='text-align:center'>
        <input type='submit' style='margin-bottom: 0px;' value='save' class='btn btn-primary' />
    </td>
</form>
```

Comment: OK.. ..well you need to add your form elements one at a time untill it breaks.  And, it will be helpfull for you if you keep to either (a) echoing, or (b) open/close PHP tags